# Creating a function that removes odd multiples in a list

Tags: python

One of the revision questions involves modifying the original list by removing all integers in a list that are both odd and a multiple of x.

```
def remove_odd_multiples(numbers_list, multiple_of):
    for ele in numbers_list:
        if (ele%2) != 0 and (ele % multiple_of) == 0:
            numbers_list.remove(ele)
    
    return numbers_list
```

Output:

```
numbers_list = [1, 5, 23, 3, 6, 17, 9, 18]
print("Before:", numbers_list)
remove_odd_multiples(numbers_list, 3)
print("After:", numbers_list)

Before: [1, 5, 23, 3, 6, 17, 9, 18]
After: [1, 5, 23, 6, 17, 18]
```

It does work, however inputting the code into coderunner, my code failed a few hidden checks which are not shown. Am I going about solving this problem wrong? Should I be using pop instead of .remove?

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. When you post here, you give SO the right to distribute the content under CC-by SA 4.0. Any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of removing while iterating, you could use a list comprehension to return a new list with the result.

```
def remove_odd_multiples(numbers_list, multiple_of):
    return [x for x in numbers_list if x % 2 == 0 or x % multiple_of != 0]
```

To modify the list in-place:

```
def remove_odd_multiples(numbers_list, multiple_of):
    numbers_list[:] = [x for x in numbers_list if x % 2 == 0 or x % multiple_of != 0]
```

Looping backwards while deleting elements also ensures that unprocessed elements are not shifted.

```
def remove_odd_multiples(numbers_list, multiple_of):
    for i in range(len(numbers_list) - 1, -1, -1):
        if (numbers_list[i]%2) != 0 and (numbers_list[i] % multiple_of) == 0:
            del numbers_list[i]
```

Comment: OP asked for and condition, also for changing the list passed as parameter.

Comment: @Niloct The `and` condition would be for removing, not keeping. The second part of my answer addresses modifying the parameter.

Comment: Might be worth short circuiting this method if `multiple_of` itself is even!

Comment: Hello, I understood the list comprehension but what does [:] do?

Comment: @didleyr6s It is used for slice assignment here, which overwrites the entire list.

Comment: @python_user why would you be so sure of that? Slice assignment is even a part of the basic language introduction https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that while iterating the list, you are also modifying it (by deleting the elements of the list).

So, try this:

```
def remove_odd_multiples(numbers_list, multiple_of):
    for ele in numbers_list[:]:
        if (ele%2) != 0 and (ele % multiple_of) == 0:
            numbers_list.remove(ele)
    
    return numbers_list
```

For more information - [Strange result when removing item from a list while iterating over it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260089/strange-result-when-removing-item-from-a-list-while-iterating-over-it)